# What are the possible ways to ensure the mysql transactions complete successfully?

Tags: mysql, validation

Let's say that you have 3 related tables and you have to do 3 mysql queries to insert/update its values. If one of them fails or inserts an unappropriate value is there a way to undo/rollback the transaction or set some constraint rules on the transactions or do you always have to check each one on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following code you can do any query.. But if one errors the querys are rolledback.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

    //do every query you need. if one errors it everything is off.

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT 
       ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
       ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
       ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
       ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
       ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
       ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```